# Changing div background image on mouseover & click in a separate location

Tags: javascript, html, css, click, mouseover

I am currently trying to hover over a background image and see a new image in a separate div. Which works (with the code below), however I cant seem to get it to change when the image is clicked. below are images representing what I am trying to accomplish.

[1 http://pkg.madisonmottdev.com/images/1.png](http://pkg.madisonmottdev.com/images/1.png)

***when hovered or clicked(same for the 2nd floor)***
[2 http://pkg.madisonmottdev.com/images/2.png](http://pkg.madisonmottdev.com/images/2.png)

Javascript code currently using for the hovering, which works properly. I just cannot figure out how to click (the first or second floor and have it change on the right). Any help is appreciated.

```
 $(window).load(function(){
        $(document).ready(function(){
            // FIRST FLOOR
            $('.floor1').mouseover(function(){
                $('.floor1').css('background', 'url("images/phase-2/first-floor-hover.a.png") no-repeat');
                $('#elevation').css('background', 'url("images/phase-2/first-floor-lg.a.png") no-repeat');
            });
            $('.floor1').mouseout(function(){
                $('.floor1').css('background', 'url("images/phase-2/first-floor.a.png") no-repeat');
                $('#elevation').css('background', 'url("images/phase-2/elevation.a.png") no-repeat');
            });

             // SECOND FLOOR
            $('.floor2').mouseover(function(){
                $('.floor2').css('background', 'url("images/phase-2/second-floor-hover.a.png") no-repeat');
                $('#elevation').css('background', 'url("images/phase-2/second-floor-lg.a.png") no-repeat');
            });
            $('.floor2').mouseout(function(){
                $('.floor2').css('background', 'url("images/phase-2/second-floor.a.png") no-repeat');
                $('#elevation').css('background', 'url("images/phase-2/elevation.a.png") no-repeat');
            });

        });
    });
```

HTML code (floor1, floor2 & elevation are set to background images with height/width):

```
        <div id="building">
                <div id="floor">
                  <div class="floor1"></div>
                </div>

                <div id="floor">
                  <div class="floor2"></div>
                </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Could you set up a test case where you display the issue? preferably in http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Also your click event function that isn't working will be nice to see.

Comment: The behavior that you want seems a bit strange given the fact the mouseover event will always happen before the user gets a chance to click on an image.

Comment: hi truth - i want to do this exactly http://jsfiddle.net/neo108/fCsNN/ but i would like to add a function where you click one of the boxes and it it stays until you click another box

Comment: see my edited answer to achieve what you're asking for in the above comment - be aware that you need to remove the mouseout() bit otherwise the background image will not "stay"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is something like this what you're after?

http://jsfiddle.net/98wuW/19/

The trick is that if you've clicked floor1, then the floor1.mouseout can't remove the floor1 image in #elevation.

As it stands, you have floor1.mouseout to change the background image of #elevation back to the default. So suppose that you hover over floor1. Then you move the mouse off floor1. The floor1.mouseout will then set the background image of #elevation back to the default.

The trick is that, when you click floor1 you've got to set a flag or something that says "keep the floor1 image in #elevation." Then in the mouseout, you can check that flag to see if you can remove the floor image in #elevation or not.

It gets a little tricky with your example, because you've got two floors, both of which could be clicked, so you've got to check two flags on each mouseout.

Answer (score 2):

nothing happens when you click because you don't have any listeners bound to the click event.

try changing part of your code to:

```
    // FIRST FLOOR
    $('.floor1').click(function(){
        $('.floor1').css('background', 'url("images/phase-2/first-floor-hover.a.png") no-repeat');
        $('#elevation').css('background', 'url("images/phase-2/first-floor-lg.a.png") no-repeat');
    });
    $('.floor1').mouseout(function(){
        $('.floor1').css('background', 'url("images/phase-2/first-floor.a.png") no-repeat');
        $('#elevation').css('background', 'url("images/phase-2/elevation.a.png") no-repeat');
    });
```

and you will see the difference in behaviour - I have changed from `mouseover` to `click` event.

you can bind multiple events to the same listener like this:

`$('.floor1').bind('click mouseover', function() {...});`

EDIT

Following your last comment, see this fiddle to achieve what you are asking for:

http://jsfiddle.net/BzPdB/

Comment: yes I know there is no call, I tried something like that before but it did not work.

Comment: do you think it could be because they are background images and not buttons or links?

Comment: background images are just css style - they have nothing to do with DOM elements. you are listening to the "click" event on a DOM element with class .floor1 and this has nothing to do with the css styles - jQuery allows you to listen to events on any type of DOM elements, regardless of what they are (buttons, links or divs)